# How do I do to use different action bar sizes for different screen sizes?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar

How can I do to define "when it's a 600dp use this size for the action bar, when it's 720 dp this other one". Will this also resize the icons??

Comment: Try creating multiple files for the same layout but for different screen sizes.

Comment: I did. I created one for the 5 inches smartphone, one for the 7 tablet and another for the 10 tablet. Everything is resized properly except the actionbar. Do I have to add something specific for the bar to resize?. Here's my code of the layout for the 10' tablet
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PEYqJepi

Comment: Did you try changing the action bar size manually in each of the layout files you've created?

Comment: No, cause I don't know what to add, that's the question, what code should I add to be able to edit it manually? I looked everywhere but there's nothing on google about this

Comment: Just change the `layout_height` attribute of the action bar in each of the layout files..

Comment: but where? I don't have any actionbar tag in the layout file I provided you  pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PEYqJepi, what should I add and where within that file?. I'm a total noob, please, It would be helpful a clear example. That file in that url is the layout of one of the activities, should I put some tag on there or in another file?

Answer (score 1):

In order to customize the size of the Action Bar for different screen sizes, you need to create a number of copies of `styles.xml` in your `values` folder. Then, customize the size of the the action bar under the theme declaration tag. Like if you want to set the Action Bar size at 600dp, do it like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="android:actionBarSize">600dp</item>

</style>
```

In this way you can have different action bar sizes for different screen sizes. And you can have as many of them as you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT :

To have more control over the action bar you must replace your action bar with the new Toolbar.

Make `Toolbar` in your `res/layout/my_layout.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

and again in your `res/layout-large-land/my_layout.xml` or `res/layout-large/my_layout.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="200dp" //different height because for layout-large-land
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

then in your activity's `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
}
```

`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` will replace your `ActionBar` with the `Toolbar`! Now you can have different attributes within your different xml's

Also make sure the Theme you apply to your activity has `NoActionBar` Attribute

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

To add more.. You can read more about the [android-design-support-library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) from the official blog post.

OLD :

The android documentation on supporting different devices is the appropriate approach to follow! You can have a good read from  [supporting-devices](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html) and [tablets-and-handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

And specifically for [supporting different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

To optimize your user experience on different screen sizes, you should create a unique layout XML file for each screen size you want to support. Each layout should be saved into the appropriate resources directory, named with a -`<screen_size>` suffix. For example, a unique layout for large screens should be saved under `res/layout-large/`.

```
MyProject/
    res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
        layout-large/        # large (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-large-land/   # large landscape
            main.xml
```

and for icons

You should always provide bitmap resources that are properly scaled to each of the generalized density buckets: `low`, `medium`, `high` and `extra-high` density. This helps you achieve good graphical quality and performance on all screen densities.

```
MyProject/
    res/
        drawable-xhdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-hdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-mdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-ldpi/
            awesomeimage.png
```

Comment: Nice to know but it doesn't answer the question. Thanks anyway. I was not the one that voted -1 for you, just in case.....I just wanted to know how to resize the actionbar, it's the only thing it's not resizing, I have done multiple layouts for multiple screen sizes already, here's the code, what could I add to resize the actionbar?

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PEYqJepi

Comment: You dont have that much control over action bar .. use toolbar with the new design support library..

Comment: It's doesn't at all, I'm sorry......be more specific, what's the "new design support library"??? can't I resize my icons either?

Comment: just by using toolbar only(without design support library) you can achieve what you want.. I have edited the ans again with a detailed example.. I can only guide you in a direction.. new design support library i have linked the blog post in the ans.. it has all the info you need to know about the new design library!